# How to parse XML with same tags using SAX parser in android?

Tags: android, saxparser

I am parsing XML which is having same tags under different elements I want parse this XML and save into respective Hash-Map and then into database.I getting problem while parsing elements having fields common 
XML I want to parse is as

```
    <NewDataSet>
     <Login>
    <LoginId>14</LoginId>
    <CompanyId>2</CompanyId>
    <UserId>14</UserId>
    <LoginName>deo5</LoginName>
    <UserPassword>Y2NzYTIwMTI=</UserPassword>
    <CreatedBy>14</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDate>2012-04-19T17:54:57.013+05:30</CreatedDate>
    <LastLogin>2012-04-19T17:54:57.013+05:30</LastLogin>
    <Status>1</Status>
    <Approved_Status>true</Approved_Status>
  </Login>
  <Login>
    <LoginId>15</LoginId>
    <CompanyId>2</CompanyId>
    <UserId>15</UserId>
    <LoginName>Philip</LoginName>
    <UserPassword>cGhpbGlwMTIz</UserPassword>
    <CreatedBy>15</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDate>2012-05-08T09:02:40.53+05:30</CreatedDate>
    <LastLogin>2012-05-08T09:02:40.53+05:30</LastLogin>
    <Status>1</Status>
    <Approved_Status>true</Approved_Status>
  </Login>
  <Login>
    <LoginId>16</LoginId>
    <CompanyId>2</CompanyId>
    <UserId>16</UserId>
    <LoginName>sagar</LoginName>
    <UserPassword>c2FnYXIyMDEy</UserPassword>
    <CreatedBy>16</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDate>2012-11-27T17:57:11.433+05:30</CreatedDate>
    <LastLogin>2012-11-27T17:57:11.433+05:30</LastLogin>
    <Status>1</Status>
    <Approved_Status>true</Approved_Status>
  </Login>
  <ProgramFamerTable>
    <ProgramFarmer_ID>1</ProgramFarmer_ID>
    <Program_ID>7</Program_ID>
    <Farmer_Code>INGUJUMAKO-2012-001</Farmer_Code>
    <Company_ID>2</Company_ID>
    <Organization_ID>1</Organization_ID>
    <Language_ID>1</Language_ID>
    <Active_Status>true</Active_Status>
    <Created_By>1</Created_By>
    <Created_Date>2012-04-24T10:30:53.823+05:30</Created_Date>
    <Delete_Status>false</Delete_Status>
    <Approved_Status>true</Approved_Status>
  </ProgramFamerTable>
  <ProgramFamerTable>
    <ProgramFarmer_ID>2</ProgramFarmer_ID>
    <Program_ID>7</Program_ID>
    <Farmer_Code>INGUJUMAKO-2012-002</Farmer_Code>
    <Company_ID>2</Company_ID>
    <Organization_ID>1</Organization_ID>
    <Language_ID>1</Language_ID>
    <Active_Status>true</Active_Status>
    <Created_By>1</Created_By>
    <Created_Date>2012-04-24T10:30:53.833+05:30</Created_Date>
    <Delete_Status>false</Delete_Status>
    <Approved_Status>true</Approved_Status>
  </ProgramFamerTable>
  <ProgramFamerTable>
    <ProgramFarmer_ID>3</ProgramFarmer_ID>
    <Program_ID>7</Program_ID>
    <Farmer_Code>INGUJUMAKO-2012-003</Farmer_Code>
    <Company_ID>2</Company_ID>
    <Organization_ID>1</Organization_ID>
    <Language_ID>1</Language_ID>
    <Active_Status>true</Active_Status>
    <Created_By>1</Created_By>
    <Created_Date>2012-04-24T10:30:53.837+05:30</Created_Date>
    <Delete_Status>false</Delete_Status>
    <Approved_Status>true</Approved_Status>
  </ProgramFamerTable>
    </NewDataSet>
```

My XML Handler is as below...

```
 public class NewMyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    String TAG = "Inside Login Element";

    //XML Fields of login file

    boolean in_Loginmain;

    boolean in_Login;
    boolean in_LoginId;
    boolean in_CompanyId;
    boolean in_UserId;
    boolean in_LoginName;
    boolean in_UserPassword;
    boolean in_CreatedBy;
    boolean in_CreatedDate;
    boolean in_UpdatedBy;
    boolean in_LastLogin;
    boolean in_Status;

    //For Database Insertion

    private static String TABLE_NAME = "AD_Login";
    private static String TABLE_NAME1 = "AD_ProgramFarmer";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    boolean in_ProgramFamerTable;
    boolean in_ProgramFarmer_ID;
    boolean in_Program_ID;
    boolean in_Farmer_Code;
    boolean in_Company_ID;
    boolean in_Organization_ID;
    boolean in_Language_ID;
    boolean in_Active_Status;
    boolean in_Created_By;
    boolean in_Created_Date;
    boolean in_Delete_Status;
    boolean in_Approved_Status;

    HashMap<String,String> map;
    //public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

    //For Farmer Registration

    HashMap<String,String> farmerMap;
    //public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> faremerlist;

    public NewMyXMLHandler(Context applicationContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        try{
        //myDataBase.beginTransaction();
        DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(applicationContext);

        dh.createDataBase();
        dh.openDataBase();

        myDataBase= dh.getWritableDatabase();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        String data = new String(ch, start, length);

            if (in_LoginId)
            {
                map.put("LoginId", data);
                Log.i("", "contactid = " + data);
            }
            if (in_CompanyId)
            {
                map.put("CompanyId", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_firstname = " + data);
            }
            if (in_UserId)
            {
                map.put("UserId", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_lastname = " + data);
            }
            if (in_LoginName)
            {
                map.put("LoginName", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_email = " + data);
            }
            if (in_UserPassword)
            {
                map.put("UserPassword", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_thumbnail = " + data);
            }
            if (in_CreatedBy)
            {
                map.put("CreatedBy", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_thumbnail = " + data);
            }
            if (in_CreatedDate)
            {
                map.put("CreatedDate", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_thumbnail = " + data);
            }
            if (in_UpdatedBy)
            {
                map.put("UpdatedBy", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_thumbnail = " + data);
            }
            if (in_LastLogin)
            {
                map.put("LastLogin", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_thumbnail = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Status)
            {
                map.put("Status", data);
                Log.i("", "contact_thumbnail = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Approved_Status)
            {
                map.put("Approved_Status", data);
                Log.i("", "Approved_Status = " + data);
            }
            //Program Farmer Started Here......
            if (in_ProgramFarmer_ID)
            {
                farmerMap.put("ProgramFarmer_ID", data);
                Log.i("", "ProgramFarmer_ID = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Program_ID)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Program_ID", data);
                Log.i("", "Program_ID = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Farmer_Code)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Farmer_Code", data);
                Log.i("", "Farmer_Code = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Company_ID)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Company_ID", data);
                Log.i("", "Company_ID = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Organization_ID)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Organization_ID", data);
                Log.i("", "Organization_ID = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Language_ID)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Language_ID", data);
                Log.i("", "Language_ID = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Active_Status)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Active_Status", data);
                Log.i("", "Active_Status = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Created_By)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Created_By", data);
                Log.i("", "Created_By = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Created_Date)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Created_Date", data);
                Log.i("", "Created_Date = " + data);
            }
            if (in_Delete_Status)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Delete_Status", data);
                Log.i("", "Delete_Status = " + data);
            }
            /*if (in_Approved_Status)
            {
                farmerMap.put("Approved_Status", data);
                Log.i("", "Approved_Status = " + data);
            }*/

    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.endDocument();
        Log.i("", "endDocument");
        myDataBase.close();
        //myDataBase.endTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        Log.i("", "endElement");
        if (localName.equals("Loginmain"))
        {
            in_Loginmain = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("Login"))
        {
            in_Login = false;
            //list.add(map); 

            Log.v(TAG, "Value of Login Element=="+map);

            //insertLoginData();



        } else if (localName.equals("LoginId"))
        {
            in_LoginId = false;
            //list.add(map);

        } else if (localName.equals("CompanyId"))
        {
            in_CompanyId = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("UserId"))
        {
            in_UserId = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("LoginName"))
        {
            in_LoginName = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("UserPassword"))
        {
            in_UserPassword = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("CreatedBy"))
        {
            in_CreatedBy = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("CreatedDate"))
        {
            in_CreatedDate = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("UpdatedBy"))
        {
            in_UpdatedBy = false;

        }
        else if (localName.equals("LastLogin"))
        {
            in_LastLogin = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("Status"))
        {
            in_Status = false;


        }else if (localName.equals("Approved_Status"))
        {
            in_Approved_Status = false;

        }//Farmer Program.........
         else if (localName.equals("ProgramFamerTable"))
        {
            in_ProgramFamerTable = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "Values of ProgramFarmerMap==="+farmerMap);
            //insertProgramFarmerData();

        } else if (localName.equals("ProgramFarmer_ID"))
        {
            in_ProgramFarmer_ID = false;


            //list.add(map);

        } else if (localName.equals("Program_ID"))
        {
            in_Program_ID = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("Farmer_Code"))
        {
            in_Farmer_Code = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("Company_ID"))
        {
            in_Company_ID = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("Organization_ID"))
        {
            in_Organization_ID = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("Language_ID"))
        {
            in_Language_ID = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("Active_Status"))
        {
            in_Active_Status = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("Created_By"))
        {
            in_Created_By = false;

        }
        else if (localName.equals("Created_Date"))
        {
            in_Created_Date = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("Delete_Status"))
        {
            in_Delete_Status = false;

        }else if (localName.equals("Approved_Status"))
        {
            in_Approved_Status = false;

        }

    }

    private void insertProgramFarmerData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{


            ContentValues cvprogramfarmer = new ContentValues();

            if (farmerMap.get("ProgramFarmer_ID") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("ProgramFarmer_ID",farmerMap.get("ProgramFarmer_ID").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Program_ID") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Program_ID", farmerMap.get("Program_ID").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Farmer_Code") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Farmer_Code", farmerMap.get("Farmer_Code").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Company_ID") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Company_ID", farmerMap.get("Company_ID").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Organization_ID") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Organization_ID", farmerMap.get("Organization_ID").toString());
            }if (farmerMap.get("Language_ID") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Language_ID", farmerMap.get("Language_ID").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Active_Status") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Active_Status", farmerMap.get("Active_Status").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Created_By") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Created_By", farmerMap.get("Created_By").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Delete_Status") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Delete_Status", farmerMap.get("Delete_Status").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Created_Date") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Created_Date", farmerMap.get("Created_Date").toString());
            }
            if (farmerMap.get("Approved_Status") != null)
            {
                cvprogramfarmer.put("Approved_Status", farmerMap.get("Approved_Status").toString());
            }


            Log.v(TAG, "Content Values=="+cvprogramfarmer);

            //myDataBase.execSQL("SELECT * FROM AD_Login");

            Log.v(TAG, "Values are inserting");

            myDataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null,cvprogramfarmer);


            Log.v(TAG, "Values are inserted");

            //cvlogin=null;

            Log.v(TAG, "Values after NULL "+cvprogramfarmer);


} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();

}

    }



    private void insertLoginData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            ContentValues cvlogin = new ContentValues();

                if (map.get("LoginId") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("LoginId", map.get("LoginId").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("CompanyId") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("CompanyId", map.get("CompanyId").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("UserId") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("UserId", map.get("UserId").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("LoginName") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("LoginName", map.get("LoginName").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("UserPassword") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("UserPassword", map.get("UserPassword").toString());
                }
                /*if (map.get("CreatedBy") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("CreatedBy", map.get("CreatedBy").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("CreatedDate") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("CreatedDate", map.get("CreatedDate").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("UpdatedBy") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("UpdatedBy", map.get("UpdatedBy").toString());
                }*/
                if (map.get("LastLogin") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("LastLogin", map.get("LastLogin").toString());
                }
                if (map.get("Status") != null)
                {
                    cvlogin.put("Status", map.get("Status").toString());
                }


                Log.v(TAG, "Values"+cvlogin);

                //myDataBase.execSQL("SELECT * FROM AD_Login");

                Log.v(TAG, "Values are inserting");

                myDataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,cvlogin);

                Log.v(TAG, "Values are inserted");

                //cvlogin=null;

                Log.v(TAG, "Values after NULL "+cvlogin);




    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.startDocument();
        Log.i("", "startDocument");
        //list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        //faremerlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        Log.i("", "startElement");

        if (localName.equals("Loginmain"))
        {
            in_Loginmain = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("Login"))
        {
            in_Login = true;
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        } else if (localName.equals("LoginId"))
        {
            in_LoginId = true;
            //list.add(map);

        } else if (localName.equals("CompanyId"))
        {
            in_CompanyId = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("UserId"))
        {
            in_UserId = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("LoginName"))
        {
            in_LoginName = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("UserPassword"))
        {
            in_UserPassword = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("CreatedBy"))
        {
            in_CreatedBy = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("CreatedDate"))
        {
            in_CreatedDate = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("UpdatedBy"))
        {
            in_UpdatedBy = true;

        }
        else if (localName.equals("LastLogin"))
        {
            in_LastLogin = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("Status"))
        {
            in_Status = true;

        }
        else if (localName.equals("Approved_Status"))
        {
            in_Approved_Status = true;

        }//Farmer Program............
        else if (localName.equals("ProgramFamerTable"))
        {
            in_ProgramFamerTable = true;
            farmerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        } else if (localName.equals("ProgramFarmer_ID"))
        {
            in_ProgramFarmer_ID = true;
            //list.add(map);

        } else if (localName.equals("Program_ID"))
        {
            in_Program_ID = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("Farmer_Code"))
        {
            in_Farmer_Code = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("Company_ID"))
        {
            in_Company_ID = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("Organization_ID"))
        {
            in_Organization_ID = true;

        } else if (localName.equals("Language_ID"))
        {
            in_Language_ID = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("Active_Status"))
        {
            in_Active_Status = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("Created_By"))
        {
            in_Created_By = true;

        }
        else if (localName.equals("Created_Date"))
        {
            in_Created_Date = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("Delete_Status"))
        {
            in_Delete_Status = true;

        }else if (localName.equals("Approved_Status"))
        {
            in_Approved_Status = true;

        }

    }
}
```